# Books on quadric surfaces

Tags: book-recommendation, quadrics

I'm looking for recommendations for books to study quadric surfaces. Not particularly for a course, just out of interest.

So what are some good textbooks on quadric surfaces?

Comment: The book published by Springer [here](https://books.google.com.hk/books/about/The_Universe_of_Quadrics.html?id=upneDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)

Comment: [Geometry and the imagination](https://archive.org/details/geometryimaginat00davi_0) by Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen starts with a few pages about quadrics.

Answer (score 1):

The topic of quadric surfaces was probably a bigger deal a century or more ago than it is now.  So many of the books are old, but the good news is that they are easily available online at sites like archive.org.

I'm learning the topic myself - like you, just out of interest and these (in no particular order) are some of the books I've gone to.

- [Salmon, *Analytic Geometry of Three Dimensions*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924050488935/page/n15/mode/2up).  An OG classic, good for both theory and recipes.
- [Sommerville, *Analytical geometry of three dimensions*](https://archive.org/details/analyticalgeomet0000somm/page/n9/mode/2up).
- [Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen, *Geometry and the imagination*](https://archive.org/details/geometryimaginat00davi_0/page/n9/mode/2up).  More of a tour of some of geometry's greatest hits, but beautifully written and a springboard to further study.
- [Spain, *Analytical quadrics*](https://archive.org/details/analyticalquadri00spai/page/n9/mode/2up).
- [Odehnal et al, *The Universe of Quadrics*](https://books.google.com.hk/books/about/The_Universe_of_Quadrics.html?id=upneDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y). This strikes me more as a collection of the authors' favorite topics in quadrics, rather than a ground up exposition.  Nevertheless, recommended.